# Not able to install iPhone app with app store distribution profile

Tags: ios, xcode4

Developed my first iPhone app for internal use and it should be distributed internally.
I am able to successfully install it on to the device when I code sign the build with my **developer profile**. But not able to install the same app(.ipa) using iTunes when code sign the build with **App store distribution profile**. I am getting the following error.

```
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: profile not valid: 0xe8008012
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 install_embedded_profile: Could not install embedded profile: -402620398
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620395
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.1JP9zU/foo_extracted/Payload/mi-ios.app
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 install_application: Could not preflight application install
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 handle_install: API failed
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 send_message: failed to send mach message of 71 bytes: 10000003
    Oct  1 15:52:32 unknown installd[462] <Error>: 001d7000 send_error: Could not send error response to client
```

I made sure the distribution profile is valid(have private key and certificate installed on my mac).

I am not sure what i am missing here. I followed every step given at iOS dev center. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The App Store profile is, as its name implies, for use *only* when distributing via the App Store. It exists for signing your app for distribution via the App Store and can't be used for any other purpose. Unless you install an app that has been signed by it *via the App Store* it will, quite correctly, fail.

If you want to distribute an app for internal use to a few devices and for a relatively short period, you should use an ad hoc profile; if to a lot if users for an extended period, you need to register as a corporate developer and follow a different process.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am already using an enterprise developer account(as a team agent) to do all this. Could you provide me a link for the different process that you are talking about?

Comment: Instead of selecting "submit to App Store", you have to select: "Save for enterprise distribution" and then select your enterprise distribution profile (which will allow you to install your ipa in any device without going through the App Store). Be careful as you are only supposed to install it on the devices you / your company own. In any others, you will be breaking the license and your account may be suspended.